# Use multiple OUTER JOINS in a CASE statement

Tags: join, db2, case

I tried to put :

```
Select .... , (CASE WHEN  (D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE = '') THEN 
coalesce(DL.C_ZONE, ' ') ELSE coalesce(D.C_ZONE, ' ' )  END ) AS     C_ZONE, 
coalesce(Z.N_ZONE,'') as N_ZONE, coalesce(Z.N_REGN,'') as N_REGN,..... FROM 
(CASE WHEN (D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE = '') THEN ( S.SNFDLR DL LEFT OUTER 
join S.SRCZNRG Z ON ( DL.C_ZONE=Z.C_ZONE )) ELSE ( S.SFDDIST D LEFT OUTER 
join S.SRCZNRG Z ON ( D.C_ZONE=Z.C_ZONE )) END ), S.SNFDLR DL, S.SFDDIST D 
..... WHERE .......
```

Basically, `C_ZONE` is supposed to be fetched from either of the two tables, `S.SNFDLR` or `S.SFDDIST`, based on whether it is null or empty.

Simultaneously, there are 2 more columns, `N_ZONE` and `N_REGN`, which are supposed to be fetched using the `C_ZONE` value from another table, `S.SRCZNRG`.

For this purpose, I need to perform a left outer join between (`S.SNFDLR` and `S.SRCZNRG`) *or* (`S.SFDDIST` and `S.SRCZNRG`), based on whichever gives me the `C_ZONE` value.

I am using a `CASE` expression for this scenario, but practically I am unable to use it properly. The `CASE` expression syntax usage is wrong. I basically want my joins to work out based on my `WHEN` condition.

Answer (score 4):

The code that produces the syntax error:

```
SELECT V.I_VIN_FIRST_9, -- many more columns 

    case when  (D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE = '') 
        then 
             (coalesce(DL.C_ZONE, ' ')  as C_ZONE    -- issue 1 here
              from S.SNFDLR DL
             ) 
        else 
             (coalesce(D.C_ZONE, ' ' )  as C_ZONE    -- same issue again
              from S.SFDDIST D
             ) 
    end

--- here is the main problem. Where is the FROM clause of the query?    

    LEFT OUTER join S.SRCZNRG Z ON ( DL.C_ZONE=Z.C_ZONE )  -- issue 3
    LEFT OUTER join S.SRCZNRG Z ON ( D.C_ZONE=Z.C_ZONE ),  -- here

    -- a few more joins

    P.PBUS P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN S.SFDDIST D 
        ON ( D.I_FRNCHZ = P.I_BUS  AND D.C_TYP IN ('X') ) 
    left outer join S.SNFDLR DL  
        on (DL.I_CUST = P.I_BUS and D.C_ZONE is null)

WHERE ... ;
```

There are three issues here:

- the main query has no `FROM` clause. The `FROM` has been hidden inside the `CASE` expression.
- the expressions inside the `CASE` (inside the `THEN` and `ELSE` parts) have no `SELECT` clause!
- you join the same table twice with the same alias.

All the above are invalid syntax.

- (and a 4th issue discussed below, mixing implicit with explicit join syntax)

It is not entirely clear what the correct solution would be. The two tables (`DL` and `D`) that are referred inside the `CASE` are also referred in the following (many joins). So, you might just simplify the `CASE` expression:

```
select 
    V.I_VIN_FIRST_9, 
   -- many more columns 

    case when  D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE = '' 
        then 
             coalesce(DL.C_ZONE, ' ')
        else 
             coalesce(D.C_ZONE, ' ' )
    end
         as C_ZONE                     -- added alias
```

and add the missing  `FROM`, rearranging the tables (a `FROM` cannot start with a `LEFT JOIN`) and combining the duplicate join into one:

```
from
    -- rearrange 
    P.PBUS as P
    left outer join S.SFDDIST as D 
        on  D.I_FRNCHZ = P.I_BUS 
        and D.C_TYP IN ('X')  
    left outer join S.SNFDLR as DL  
        on  DL.I_CUST = P.I_BUS 
        and (D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE = '') 

    -- combine the two joins in one
    left outer join S.SRCZNRG as Z 
        on  case when  D.C_ZONE is null or D.C_ZONE 
                then DL.C_ZONE else D.C_ZONE
            end = Z.C_ZONE
```

Since we are rewriting, lets also (solve the 4th issue). This is not needed but mixing implicit with explicit join syntax can be confusing and error-prone.
So lets convert the implicit join syntax to explicit `JOIN` by moving the conditions from `WHERE` to where they belong (`ON` clauses):

```
    inner join S.SRCXDTL as V
        on  V.I_BUS = P.I_BUS  
    inner join S.SRCXDEF as F
        on  V.I_VHCL_RECAL     = F.I_VHCL_RECAL 
        and V.I_VHCL_RECAL_SEQ = F.I_VHCL_RECAL_SEQ
    inner join S.SVEHW as W
        on  V.I_PRTITN     = W.I_PRTITN    
        and V.I_VHCL_SAN   = W.I_VHCL_SAN 
        and V.I_VIN_LAST_8 = W.I_VIN_LAST_8
```

and keeping only the non-joining condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
where   V.I_VHCL_RECAL = 'X05' 
  and   V.I_VIN_LAST_8 > ' ' 
  and   V.I_VIN_FIRST_9 > ' ' 
  and   V.I_BUS between 0 and 99999999999 
  and   V.I_PRTITN in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
  and   V.I_VHCL_SAN between 0 and 99999999999 ;
```